# Infinite scrolling with will_paginate. Issue removing element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-scroll, will-paginate

I'm implementing infinite scroll with will_paginate and ajax. Whenever I press the 'load more' elements, it brings me the next 4 elements in the collection. At the moment, everything is ok. But when I remove some element of some page, the next page has been already established in the 'load more' button; because of this, the next time I press the 'load more' button, one element is skipped. Does anybody know how can I solve this? (Sorry about my english)

Comment: this question is a little unclear,  are you saying that when you delete an element from your page, that the next load page is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Pagination gems don't work very well in your use case.

The easiest way to solve this is: if you have a list of elements ordered by e.g. id, on your next page request send the id of the last element on the current page, and use it to offset the next page.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that pagination isn't eager loading the next set, but instead is doing an offset count

```
initial index + page_length * (page number - 1)
limit page_length
```

When you delete an element it forward shifts the index of every element after it in the database for this query. Which leaves your front end element indexes at a different state than the backend has.

You will need to re-load every "page" starting with the one containing the deleted element and work to the latest loaded "page" to get the front end to have the same element indexes that the back end has.